# Context lost when IClientMessageInspector is configured on a WCF service and method is called with async/await

Tags: asp.net, wcf, async-await

TLDR: does anyone knows how is context synchronization done when `IClientMessageInspector` is configured on a service called with await/async without `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

We have a .NET FW4.5+ project in which we generated a proxy class using WcfUtils. In this proxy, there are Async version of the different methods.

Also, in our web.config, we have a custom <del>(but out of our control)</del> `BehaviourExtensionElement` in the `system.serviceModel` section which in turn will register a custom `IClientMessageInspector`. This inspector, when its `AfterReceiveReply` method is called, at some point, will use `HttpContext.Current.Items[stringKey]`.

The problem is that even though I have no ConfigureAwait(false) anywhere in the execution path, `HttpContext.Current` returns null. I've been trying to log the execution and the context is present all the way up to the async call to `base.Channel.MyMethod` and even after since the WcfUtil proxy is generated without await (simply a return Task).

I've searched a lot on google but wasn't able to find anything specific about how continuation is done when there is a MessageInspector though I can't fathom why it would be different from the synchronization for the main call.

**Edit: Used a Men in the middle inspector**

I created a dummy MessageInspector that receives the messages and passes them to that is normaly configured. This allowed me to realize that ALL calls done with await don't have a context when entering the Inspector: the authenticated user is now the app pool user and `HttpContext.Current` is null. I also printed the stack at execution and it looks something like this.

```
à MyNamespace.InTheMiddleMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(Message& reply, Object correlationState) dans D:\Builds\sfpauw14759_1\_work\379\s\Client\AccueilClient\SX00.SXCLT00A.AccueilClient\InTheMiddleMessageInspector.cs:ligne 76
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.AfterReceiveReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
à System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
à System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass44_0`3.<FromAsyncImpl>b__0(IAsyncResult iar)
à System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishSend(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.SendCallback(IAsyncResult result)
à System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
à System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
à System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
à System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
à System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
à System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
à System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
à System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32 bytesRead, WebExceptionStatus errorStatus)
à System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
à System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
à System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
à System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
à System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

**Edit: Context is back after MessageInspector**

Once we get back to the main code *branch*, the context is back and the stack is

```
à MyNamespace.MyClass.<MyMethodAsync>d__5`2.MoveNext()
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
à System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(Action action)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
à System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

It seems there is something wrong with how ASP.NET handles calling the MessageInspector.

Comment: `We have a .NET FW4.2+ project` You have to use 4.5 with a 4.5+ runtime _and_ with `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to 4.5 or newer. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#before-getting-started).

Comment: Change to .Net 4.5 and turn off quirks mode. Then run the code and post some logs if it fails again.  Also avoid using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET.

Comment: We no are in 4.5+ with TargetFramework set to 4.5 in web.config (in fact, the web project itself and the dummyInspector are in 4.8 though the MessageInspector we don't control is in 4.5). Looks like I misread. Ever heard of dislexia? :P Note that the problem is ONLY in the Inspector. As soon as we get back to the main code, the context is back.

Comment: @Jiayao: I think I now see why you were talking about `Task.Run` but it is not htat, it is `System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run` and it is called by the framework, not by me.

Comment: Are there any other errors after the context comes back?

Comment: No, everything works fine (except obviously, that the MessageInspector didn't do what it was supposed to).